# How can i call tshark with arguments under windows?

Tags: python, cmd, tshark

I want to port my script from linux to windows, and i am having problem with the windows cmd.

This is the command i want to run:
tshark -r input.pcap -T pdml > output.xml

It works fine when i directly enter it in cmd, however I am having problems with the os.system() function. How can i do that?

Comment: What does *"having problems"* mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your problem is the redirection. It is handled by the command interpreter, so you have to execute

```
cmd /c "tshark -r input.pcap -T pdml > output.xml"
```